# 3D Barplot in which the depth of the bars visualize a variable in R

Tags: r, plot, 3d

To complete a task for my university, I need to visualise three biological variables as well as the result of their interplay in a 3D plot:
A = concentration of a pollutant 
B = percentage contribution of an important functional group to the overall abundance of plankton 
C = the overall abundance of plankton
D = binary system answer

As I only have eight samples (one for each of the eight levels of pollutant), I don’t think a 3D surface is viable. Hence, my idea was to create a **barplot in which the depth of the bars represents variable B**:
x1-axis: variable A,
x2-axis: variable B,
x3-axis: variable C and
colour of the bars: variable D.
For clarity I would also need labelled breaks in the x1-x2 and x1-x3 plane (which I know how to do in 2D).

Sample Data:

```
A <- c(0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.9)
B <- c(0.05,0.1,0.5,0.55,0.1)
C <- c(10,15,50,55,8)
D <- c(0,0,1,1,0)
data <- data.frame(A,B,C,D)
```

The corresponding plot should look like this:
[image]

So far, I only found bar3d.ad() (https://rdrr.io/cran/epade/man/bar3d.ade.html) or legoplots (https://www.r-bloggers.com/2015/08/legoplots-in-r-3d-barplots-in-r/), which both don't provide the option of assigning a variable to the depth of the bar.

I would be super thankful for all suggestions on how to implement this graph in R (either using a package for plotting or constructing it step by step myself as an image) as well as alternative ideas for 3D plotting!